# fswebcam not displaying images properly

Tags: webcam, fswebcam

Some of the images I get from the Webcam using `fswebcam` are not displaying properly.

Comparison:

[image][image]

I got these images using the following command:

```
sudo fswebcam -r 640x480 test.jpg
```

I'm having the same issues with 320x240 resolution.

**EDIT:**

I've also tried skipping some frames before getting the picture:

```
  sudo fswebcam -r 640x480 -S 20 test.jpg
```

And, although I am getting less malformed images I'm still getting a lot (1 every 6-7 taken)

What can I do to solve this output problem?

Comment: would you mind to elaborate, how did you get the first and the second images, and what result you're looking for?

Comment: @lenik I got both results by using the same command, same specifications. I would like to always get a complete and good drawn picture like the first one.

Comment: I get similar issues with the Pi Camera module. Weird alignment problems. But I use ffmpeg and raspicam/raspistill. Not sure if related. How often does that happen to you?

Comment: @ppumkin Normally every 10-15 photos. Sometimes every 4-5.

Comment: Even though old question, still top in google.. Some times this is also a case of taking two many shots one after the other.. Slow down your frame rate.. But as in try doing something like 1 frame every 5 seconds and see if it appears then decrease the timer until you find the limit.. This is most likely a power draw issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a similar issue as well. To get rid of those malformed images try:

> sudo fswebcam -r 640x480 test.jpg -S 2

. The -S instructs it to skip a number of frames,in this case two.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried, but still having the same problem with -S 20. Not as much as without -S (as I was getting constant malformed) but still getting every 5-6 photos.

Answer (score 1):

I am onto my second camera  On my first cam I had constant broken images.  They are proper files but the picture is distorted.

I am now using a Logitech c270 that i got cheap of an auction site.   Initially i had some color issues because i over compensated for the previous camera.

Here is my current line

```
 fswebcam -d /dev/video0  -S 2 -s brightness=60% -s Contrast=15%  -s Gamma=50%  -p YUYV -r 1280x720 --jpeg 80 -s Sharpness=40% -s Saturation=15%   --title "New Zealand - Wellington - Tawa"  $DIR/$filename
```

Comment: This seems a comment about your own experiences not an answer. Do you have a solution for the problem from your experience?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! After tweaking the motion.conf file for a couple of minutes I've came to this conclusion: NEVER use higher framerates than 30 for a webcam (30fps is more than enough to work on any decent camera, so higher fps just stresses the camera beyond its limits ). In conf. file (after installing motion, type in Cli: sudo nano /etc/motion/motion.conf), set the "framerate" to 30 and "webcam_maxrate" to 30. Problem solved!
P.S.-don't use higher resolutions than 640 x 480 !

Answer (score 0):

@darius solution does not help at all, as it seems to be related to motion, not directly to fswebcam.

For me, using a really low framerate, and skipping frames, seems to have helped a bit (not much). Something like

```
fswebcam --fps 15 -S 8 -r 640x480 $DATE.jpg
```

Comment: Welcome to rpi@stackexchange. This should probably be a comment, rather than an answer on its own.

Comment: Should it? I gave a solution

Answer (score 0):

Problem with images?

You must generate images into a directory example one image per second

/cam
20160729154102.jpg  29-Jul-2016 18:40   132K
20160729154202.jpg  29-Jul-2016 18:41   132K

and  view the one
generate other and delete the first

Ex: /cam.jpg in other directory

**The image to view:**
/cam.jpg
**The directory with the images:**
/cam

When view the image, the same in totally downloading (cm.jpg)
otherwise you view the last image in some time that is downloading and some times have an error.

```
**PHP script (execute with cron every minute)**

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires" ) ;
?>
<!--<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">-->
<?
  $directory="cam";
    $dirint = dir($directory);
    while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
    {         
      $archivos[$archivo] = $archivo; 
    }


 rsort ($archivos);


 foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {   

      $e=$e+1;

      if($e>2){

         $file='cam/'.$archivo;
          unlink($file);
      }               


 }


 foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {      

               if(preg_match('/jpg/',$archivo)){ 


                       $r=$r+1;                    
                       $alto =400;                 

                        if($r<3){
                                $file='cam/'.$archivo;                  
                            $salida = '<img src="'.$file.'">';  



                               $newfile='cam.jpg';      
                               if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
                                echo "failed to copy<br>";
                                 }                              
                                /*
                               if (!copy($file,'capturas/'. $archivo)) {
                                echo "failed to copy<br>";
                                 }                          
                                */
                        }               


            }
 }      
    $dirint->close();


    ?>

    <div align="center">
    <?
    echo $salida;   
    ?>

    </div>
```

**see the sample running:**
http://diarionecochea.mobi/camarita/camara.html

Answer (score 0):

I was getting only a dark picture (no detail at all) when I ran fswebcam image.jpg. However, I got a good picture when I ran

fswebcam --fps 15 -S 8 image.jpg

as suggested by Alexandre Strube in the answers. Thank you.